# Reverse for 'profile_info_update' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile_info_update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: django

It is basically an e-Commerce website. Everything working perfectly but When I **log out** then occurs the below error. What will be the relevant solution?

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'profile_info_update' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile_info_update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'profile_info_update' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile_info_update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\DCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\DCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\Business_Website',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 16 May 2022 15:31:17 +0000
```

***template:***

```
<a href="{% url 'profile_info_update' user.pk %}" class="edit_btn btn">
    edit
</a>
```

***urls.py:***

```
path('profile_info_update/<int:pk>', views.profile_info_update.as_view(), name="profile_info_update")
```

***views:***

```
class profile_info_update(UpdateView):
    model = User
    from_class = change_profile_info
    fields = 'first_name','last_name','email'                                                                
    template_name = '33_change_profile_info.html'
    success_url =("/")
```

***forms.py:***

```
class change_profile_info(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':"form-control"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':"form-control"}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':"form-control"}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{% url 'profile_info_update' user.pk %}" class="edit_btn btn">
     edit
</a>
{% endif %}
```

Now I applied it and not showing any error. I answered my own question so that others can get help.